# A d20, a d10 and a comparison

Tags: probability, dice

> You roll a 20-sided die and a 10-sided die. What's the probability that the 10- sided die shows a greater value?

The probability of the d20 showing 1-10 is $\frac12$. In this case, one has two d10s effectively. For one die to be greater than the other:
$$P=\frac{1-\frac1{10}}2=\frac9{20}$$ So the result is $\frac9{20}\cdot\frac12=22.5\%$?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The number shown on the 10 die is greater than the number shown on 20 die if the point $(i,j)$ lies above the line shown in the picture. There are $45$ such pairs and hence the probability is $\frac{45}{200} = \frac{9}{40}$

Comment: Right, in other words $$P={{10} \choose {2}}/200=9/40=0.225$$

Comment: @Muralidharan A+ for the visualization

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $22.5\%$ is right. Here's another approach using sums:

The probability that the $10$ sided die beats the $20$ sided die depends on the combinations of outcomes. Let $a$ be the outcome of the $10$-sided die, and $b$ be the outcome of the $20$-sided die. Then:

$$P = \dfrac{\sum_{b=1}^{9} \sum_{a=b+1}^{10} (1)}{20 \cdot 10} = \dfrac{\sum_{b=1}^{9}(10-b)}{200} =\dfrac{45}{200} = \dfrac{9}{40} = .225$$